# Objective-C UIScrollView not scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have never used UIScrollView before, so I apologize in advanced if my question seems dumb.

I add a UIScrollView to my storyboard scene and then I added labels inside my the scrollview. But when I run my app nothing scrolls. and my text runs off the app screen. Here is a screenshot of the list of items inside my storyboard scene

My question is, is there any steps I may have missed to get this working?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set this in code:

```
// the size dimensions should be larger than the scroll view's frame size.
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(xSize, ySize);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because scrollView has contentSize property which is not set yet. So it's not scrolling. To do it in code you should try out David's answer to try it in storyboard, you should add these constraints

These two constraints will make height-

- scrollview vertical space to toolbar(bottom constarint)
- scollView vertical space to launchImage(top constraint)

These two will make width

- scrollView leading space to container/superView
- scrollView trailing space to container/superView